# How to do performance Testing of Pub-nub android application?

Tags: android, sockets, performance-testing, simulate, pubnub

I am using Pub-nub in my application. Basically it will work based on subscribe or publish. I have used Pub-nub for sending push message from mobile device to server and vice-verse as two way connection.

I have subscribed to one channel and publishing some message to that channel from one device.

I want to do the same by simulating n number of devices.

Each mobile device have separate channel to communicate with web server. So there will be n number of socket connection between each android device and web server.

How to simulate n number of devices to do the performance testing of android app and web server.

Help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PubNub offers mobile app deployment simulation services reach out to us!  Also you can use `ab` apache bench to simulate web server requests.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html and here is an example: `ab -n 100 -c 10 http://pubsub.pubnub.com/time/0` and you can install AB by `apt-get install apache2-utils`.